# Different values for the Build Location for different XCode projects

Tags: ios, xcode, build

The two projects I'm working on happen to both make use of XCode at some point during building.

One project is based on Reactive Native, in which case I'd need to set the Build Location to `Custom` with

```
Products: build/Build/Products
Intermediates: build/Build/Intermediates
```

[image]

in order for the command `react-native run-ios` to run properly ([or else I'd run into `CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist` error](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308)).

Another project is based on Unity and make use of a custom framework injection, in which case I'd need to set the Build Location to `Legacy` as there is a custom script that uses the value in the target settings.

[image]

---

To my astonishment I discovered that every time I work on the other project I'd need to reset the Build Location value to the right one for the project or else I'll run into errors/problems.

Is there a way to define a project-specific configuration so that I can have different values for the Build Location for different XCode projects?

One solution I can think of is to stick to `Legacy`: for the project based on react-native simply define the build location as `build/Build/Products` in the target settings. But the drawback is that react native may just override the value to the default one at each build and rendering this approach not practical (I have yet tested it out though).

So I'm wondering if there is a "standard" way of resolving this annoying problem.